# Difficulties with basic Spring Security Configuration

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-roo

I'm trying to build a very basic, straight-forward authentication for a spring project.

The problem I'm having is that the application constantly sends me to the "login-failed" page, although I've declared 2 basic accounts (admin and user).

my application-Security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login/denied" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/*Details/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    </http>
    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- SHA-256 values can be produced using 'echo -n your_desired_password | sha256sum' (using normal *nix environments) -->
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

my VERY basic login-form:

```
<form action="/${app_name}/resources/j_spring_security_check" method="POST">
        <label for="j_username">Username</label>
        <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" /><br/>

        <label for="j_password">Password</label>
        <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" /><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
```

For now the controller is there only to resolve the URLs for login, login/denied etc.

I'm just starting out with Spring and Roo, so this might just be something obvious that I'm overlooking.

Thanks to anyone taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have defined a **password-encoder**

```
<password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
```

while your password is plain text

```
<user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

Either remove the encoder or (better) specify the password, encoded with the algorithm you have chosen (sha-256)